# min and max from a variable of type number in JS

Tags: javascript

I was studying min and max methods in JavaScript and I couldnt find any post that explain these methods algorithms. My guess is that in numerical variable like 1234 you can get min and max by splitting the number in 4 values and compare them. Or add these values in array, sort that array and get min as array[0]. Is there any post related to these methods explained?

Comment: try here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: You can just do `Math.max.apply(Math, '1234'.split(''));`

Comment: Exactly how the native functions are implented, is browser specific, and up to the vendor, as long as they return a result according to the ECMA spec.

Comment: @adeno I was about to suggest that the [MDN documentation for `.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) has a good illustration of `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`.  Your example is similar to Mozilla's.

Comment: @adeneo thx for your comment but i've already understood min and max methods and i couldnt understand the code in back. I'd like to see a code or explained pseudocode of how these methods works.

Comment: So you're asking how they work internally, it's a bit unclear? In that case, see my commment above, it's up to the browser vendor how they want to do it in their javascript engines, as long it's up to spec.

Comment: The simplest method is to iterate over numbers, noting down the highest/lowest value encountered so far. No algorithm necessary. Sorting or anything else will take longer.

Comment: @adeneo yeah, i was asking for an example of how they do it using algorithms. I've checked rojo 's link to MDN but they still use methods.

Comment: To know what the different browsers do, and how the javascript engines work, you have to look at the source, and chrome, firefox etc. are open source -> **https://code.google.com/p/v8/**

Comment: @adeneo and rojo, interesting comments! i'll check your link's for more info. Thx

Answer (score 1):

`Math.min` and `Math.max` are returning you the minimum and the maximum value respectively from the set of passed arguments.
So that you can just split a string representation of your number to retrieve an array of digits and then apply `Math.min` or `Math.max` methods to the result array.

```js
(function() {
  var minDigit,
      maxDigit,
      numToDigitsArray;
  
  numToDigitsArray = function(num) {
    return ('' + Math.abs(num)).split('').map(function(digit) {
      return parseInt(digit);
    });
  };
  
  minDigit = function(num) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, numToDigitsArray(num));
  };
  
  maxDigit = function(num) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, numToDigitsArray(num));
  };
  
  console.log(minDigit(-5343240123));
  console.log(maxDigit(753943240123));
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current source of the [v8 JavaScript Engine](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/Source), `/build/v8/src/math.js` defines `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` thusly:

**Math.min:**

```
// ECMA 262 - 15.8.2.12
function MathMin(arg1, arg2) {  // length == 2
  var length = %_ArgumentsLength();
  if (length == 2) {
    arg1 = TO_NUMBER_INLINE(arg1);
    arg2 = TO_NUMBER_INLINE(arg2);
    if (arg2 > arg1) return arg1;
    if (arg1 > arg2) return arg2;
    if (arg1 == arg2) {
      // Make sure -0 is considered less than +0.
      return (arg1 === 0 && %_IsMinusZero(arg1)) ? arg1 : arg2;
    }
    // All comparisons failed, one of the arguments must be NaN.
    return NAN;
  }
  var r = INFINITY;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var n = %_Arguments(i);
    if (!IS_NUMBER(n)) n = NonNumberToNumber(n);
    // Make sure -0 is considered less than +0.
    if (NUMBER_IS_NAN(n) || n < r || (r === 0 && n === 0 && %_IsMinusZero(n))) {
      r = n;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

**Math.max:**

```
// ECMA 262 - 15.8.2.11
function MathMax(arg1, arg2) {  // length == 2
  var length = %_ArgumentsLength();
  if (length == 2) {
    arg1 = TO_NUMBER_INLINE(arg1);
    arg2 = TO_NUMBER_INLINE(arg2);
    if (arg2 > arg1) return arg2;
    if (arg1 > arg2) return arg1;
    if (arg1 == arg2) {
      // Make sure -0 is considered less than +0.
      return (arg1 === 0 && %_IsMinusZero(arg1)) ? arg2 : arg1;
    }
    // All comparisons failed, one of the arguments must be NaN.
    return NAN;
  }
  var r = -INFINITY;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var n = %_Arguments(i);
    if (!IS_NUMBER(n)) n = NonNumberToNumber(n);
    // Make sure +0 is considered greater than -0.
    if (NUMBER_IS_NAN(n) || n > r || (r === 0 && n === 0 && %_IsMinusZero(r))) {
      r = n;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

If you use [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`, you can get the minimum or maximum value for a sequence of numbers.

(borrowing from adeneo's comment above because I'm lazy:)

```
Math.max.apply(Math, '1234'.split(''));
// returns 4
```